# PDF of an exponential distribution with varying paramter, lambda

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, exponential-distribution

Suppose that the lifetime of a device is exponential with rate λ, but suppose
also that the value of λ is not fixed but is itself a random variable that is
uniform in the range [a, b) with 0 < a.

Can the pdf of the lifetime of the device be written as:

$ \lambda = \begin{cases} 0, x < a\\ \dfrac {1} {b-a} , a\leq x < b\\ 0,  x\geq b \end{cases} $

Comment: The PDF of $\lambda$, or the PDF of the lifetime of the device?

Comment: If $\lambda$ is Uniform on $[a,b)$, then the PDF would be 0 for $x\geq b$.

Comment: What you wrote is the PDF of the random variable $\lambda$, not the PDF of the device lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

Let $T|\lambda \sim \text{Exp}(\lambda)$ be the lifetime of the device and let $\lambda \sim \text{U}[a,b)$ be the parameter.  Then for all $t \geqslant 0$ you have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
f_T(t) 
&= \int \limits_a^b p(T=t|\lambda) \pi(\lambda) d\lambda \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{a-b} \int \limits_a^b \exp(-\lambda t) d\lambda \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{a-b} \Bigg[ - \frac{1}{t} \cdot \exp(-\lambda t) \Bigg]_{\lambda=a}^{\lambda=b} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{a-b} \Bigg[ \frac{\exp(-at) - \exp(-bt)}{t} \Bigg] \\[6pt]
&= \frac{e^{-at} - e^{-bt}}{a-b} \cdot  \frac{1}{t}. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Comment: So, this has to take into account the law of total probability, thanks for that.

Comment: Yes, the first step is an application of that law.